# site not found after deploying a flutter firebase app using firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

so i have an app using flutter and firebase, everything works well on my local host and i wanted to deploy it using firebase hosting. i've run "flutter build web", then "npm install -g firebase-tools" first and then firebase deploy and i've received a link for the domain. when i want to access this link : https://swipeaway-7195c.firebaseapp.com
i got :

Site Not Found

### Why am I seeing this?

There are a few potential reasons:

1. You haven't deployed an app yet.
2. You may have deployed an empty directory.
3. This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.

### How can I deploy my first app?

Refer to our [hosting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) to get started.

and i have the /build/web folder that is not empty...what should i do?

so i have an app using flutter and firebase, everything works well on my local host and i wanted to deploy it using firebase hosting. i've run "flutter build web", then "npm install -g firebase-tools" first and then firebase deploy and i've received a link for the domain. when i want to access this link : https://swipeaway-7195c.firebaseapp.com
i got :

Site Not Found

Comment: Seems to work for me now.